# Replace() and iterating through cells

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I have a column formatted as date and I want to remove the period chars so that in every cell I have ***ddmmYYYY*** instead of ***dd.mm.YYYY***.

I thought I'd have to use the Replace function to remove the '.' char with an empty string "", but I can't figure out how to use the Replace() function correctly.

This would be the "easy" solution:

```
Sub NewReplace()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Replace(".","")
 
End Sub
```

I tried to use a foor loop as well.

```
Sub Replace()

Dim date_range As Range
Set date_range = Columns(3)

For Each cell In date_range.Cells

cell.Replace(".","")

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not have to replace anything. Excel keeps `Date` as number! What you see in only the **format**. You cannot change the format in that way. Sou you should only use a code line: `date_range.NumberFormat = "ddmmyyyy")`...

Comment: @FaneDuru, that is on the presumption the data in the cells are indeed identified as `Date`... which may need to be checked beforehand..:-)

Comment: Oh, alright ,thank you! That's a much more elegant solution. This will be useful for other miniprojects I have in mind too :)

Comment: @mtholen in this case they are formatted as date. Out of curiosity, what if that weren't the case? For example if someone wrote the dates as simple text and did not format the cells as 'Date'. Would the use of the Replace() function make sense then?

Comment: In that case I would use `Split(".")` so you can create a `Date` object using `DateSerial(<year>, <month>, <day>)` and subsequently format the `Date` object as required.

Comment: And, by the way; the `Replace` should be used like so: `Replace(<your text>, ".", vbNullString)` if you want to remove all "."

Comment: Or, instead of using the `Replace` function, you could use the `Range.Replace` method which would get rid of the loop, since you can apply it to a multi-cell range.

Comment: @mtholen Of course, but it is stated in the question: "I have a column formatted as date" and proved by the fact that `Replace` does not work...

Answer (score 0):

```
‘iterate to each cell in range

For Each cell In date_range.Cells

    with cell
        ‘change the value of the cell replacing “.” to “”. Instead of “” you can also use vbNullString. With Cstr you convert the value to String, so the result it’s not a number.
        .value= CStr(Replace(.value, ".","")

    end with

End Sub
```

Cstr is to convert variables to string. CInt to convert to Integer Number, CBool to boolean, Clng to Long Integer, CDate to date… and much more convertes!

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?